# Shiny selectizeInput, adding to input when multiple=TRUE

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using Shiny to create a simple dashboard for users to modify app settings. They can add or remove elements from the app and also create new elements of certain types into the repository for other people to use.

I'm using selectizeInput to store the selected elements (searched from the database) in one tab, and in the adjacent tab the user has the option to create a new element and store it into the database.

What I want to do is to add the newly created element directly into the selectizeInput, but simply getting the value using input$factor_selector and then appending to it and calling updateSelectizeInput with the appended list is not working. I'm not sure what the object types actually are for the selectizeInput and what I should be inputting for the 'selected' variable when calling updateSelectizeInput

Here is a code example:

```
values = input$factor_selector
values[[length(values)+1]] <- js["key"]
updateSelectizeInput(session, "factor_selector", selected=values)
```

Should the update have other parameters set too, e.g. choices or options?
I'm also not sure how the selectizeInput handles the names and keys for the items, since the input only returns the keys, but I assume when setting a new value it should also have a key.

Here is the code for generating the input:

```
selectizeInput('factor_selector', 'Select factor(s)', multiple=TRUE, choices='',
   options = list(
     valueField = 'key',
     labelField = 'name',
     searchField = 'name',
     options = list(),
     create = FALSE,
     maxItems = 20,
     render = I("{
      option: function(item, escape) {removed this for readability}
  }"),
  score = I("function(search) {removed this for readability}"),
  load = I("function(query, callback) {removed this for readability)
    )
  )
```

The input works like I want it to otherwise, I'm just having trouble finding out the correct way to update and refresh the selected items.

Comment: I think you should update options and value at the same updateSelectizeInput call. Options my have a list or names vector type, then name will be on the front end, and value will go to a back end.

Comment: but what should I pass as the selected variable for update? is it just a list ?

Comment: it should be the old selected plus something new you want to add.

Comment: Yeah that much I understood. But what is the type of the list of old selected items and *how* should I add to it? Is it a list? A data frame? Do I just append to it? What type variable do I pass as the new selected list?

Comment: I think you should create  a reactiveValue variable to keep the update. Start from the initial options for the list, say, select_input=  c(name = value). Every time when you want to update options, do c(select_input, c(new_name, new_value)). And updateSelectInput(, options = select_input, value = c(old_selected, something_new)).